# Intuitive explanation for markov chain why a state is called aperiodic if period of state is one?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

From the definition, if a state's period is one, we call this state aperiodic. It's pretty counterintuitive.

For example, the naive case

[image]

Obviously, it will come back to state `a` after $1, 2, 3, \cdots$ iterations. Why will we call this state aperiodic? Are there some intuitive considerations?

The definition of aperiodic state can be found:

1. In [this website](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_4_classification_of_states.php), the definition is below Fig 11.11
2. [Markov Chains and Mixing Times
   By David Asher Levin](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Markov_Chains_and_Mixing_Times/f208DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA7&printsec=frontcover), in page 7.

For @geetha290krm 's comment, I've posted the following part in another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4639488/481713).

I have another related question is why define period of state i as $d_i \equiv perd(i) = \gcd\{n | P^n_{ii} > 0\}$. Since we cannot necessarily go back to state i after $d_i$ iterations.

For example,

[image]

If we start from state $1$, we can only go back to $1$ after $\{6, 9, 12, 15, 18, \cdots\}$ iterations. Although $\gcd = 3$, $(P^3)_{11} = 0$. However, we still say the period of state $1$ is $3$.

Comment: where are you getting your definitions from?

Comment: If $p$ is a period exceeding $1$ then the chain returns to the state  after $p$ units of time. This does not apply to period $1$.Compare with the definition of  prime number. If $p$ has  divisor greater than $1$ then it is a composite number but even prime numbers have $1$ as  a divisor.

Comment: @user24142 For example, in [this website](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_4_classification_of_states.php) the definition is below fig 11.11

Comment: It makes sense to speak of a period if the chain has a positive chance to be back at $a$ only every two steps, or every three steps, or more generally, every $k$ steps with $k\ge2$. A period of $k=1$ where $P(X_n=a\mid X_0=a)>0$ for all $n\ge1$ is a rather trivial period, don't you think? So the state is not really “periodic” in this case.

Comment: @geetha290krm How to explain the 2nd example in my updated question?

Answer (score 2):

Some intuitive considerations come from comparison with signals.

A signal $x(t)$ with period T satisfies $x(t+T)=x(t)$. The period is defined as the minimum T to satisfy the equality, not any possible multiple of it. Constant signals, similar to your chain, do not have a defined period.

Would the period of a constant be $0$, as the limit of some minimum, or rather the frequency $0$ and therefore the period... what, positive infinite?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have another question in 2nd example of my updated post. It's quite strange for markov chain, since it can have $x(t) = x(t + 2T) = x(t + 3T)$ but $x(t) \neq x(t + T)$, but we still call its period $T$.